# XSLT header problems

Tags: xml, xslt, header, namespaces, root

Current header

```
<Invoice xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Factuur_insbou003.xsd">
```

New header

```
<Invoice xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
         xmlns="http://www.gs1.nl/factuur/insbou/004" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.gs1.nl/factuur/insbou/004 
                             Factuur_insbou004.xsd">
```

I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*[local-name()= 'Invoice']">
    <Invoice xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
             xmlns="http://www.gs1.nl/factuur/insbou/004"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
    </Invoice>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You are right (deleted the wrong code), my problem is to create  xmlns="http://www.gs1.nl/factuur/insbou/004". Hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is...

Comment: The problem: i cant add  xmlns="http://www.gs1.nl/factuur/insbou/004"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand that the namespace is part of the qualified name of each element in the document so you need to change the namespace of each using e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and then on your stylesheet root you can simply declare the namespace you want. But as you additionally want to add an attribute to the root element and omit another one you also need a template doing that, so with all changes you need

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
         version="1.0"      
         xmlns="http://www.gs1.nl/factuur/insbou/004" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Invoice">
      <Invoice 
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.gs1.nl/factuur/insbou/004 
                            Factuur_insbou004.xsd">
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </Invoice>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```